USB-C port as a power delivery and data transfer
I am working on a PCB that has a USB-C port designed as a power delivery port and a data transfer bus. I put resistors with values of 10k on the CC1 and CC2 pins to enable enough current through the USB port. The issue I have is about having both the PD activated while receiving or sending data from this USB port. I want the communication working in this sense:

I have a ESP32 on a side and an android device on another
I'd like the ESP32 charging the android device while the data is being transferred from the ESP or from the tablet

For now, I have either the charging mode, or the data delivery mode. When not using any OTG cable, I only have my phone being charged from the PCB, when I am using OTG cable, depending of the side that I plug, I have either data transfer or PD. The USB-C port is a 2.0 USB-C connector so it should work properly, but I miss something here.
If you need the schematics I can provide the schematic of the USB-C port, I can do the same for the code. I am using a USB-UART driver FT231XS-R to switch differential data signals from USB to UART.
I have tried several cables between 2 android devices with and without OTG and with lot of them I can charge and access to files inside another device while connected.
I also tried to change thee resistors values on CC1 and CC2 pins but it doesn't seem to change anything. I put 22k resistors to enable 3A to go through the USB-C. Don't worry, the circuit is designed to support 4A peak intensity.
I tried to measure the current flow inside thee USB-C charger from the PCB and when I connect my phone for example I have a standard current flow of 0.3Amps. However, when I have the data transfer detected on my phone, it is not charging because the current flow is limited to 0.12Amps.
What can I do to have both functions activated?
Here is the schematic of the USB-C connexion on the PCB : 

What kind of USB port is on tablet? Type-C has no special OTG cables so is it MicroUSB? Is the cable MicroUSB plug to Type-C plug?

The tablette is a samsung sm-t500 with a usb c type inside, i haven't opened it to see clearly which type is it but it is at least a 2.0 type so it should work. Yes I have a MicroUSB plug to Type-C plug but also a usb TPe-C plug to Type-C plug and both are working for either the PD or the data delivery. I used both between my Pixel 7 and the tablet and the tablette is charging my phone and the phone is detected by the tablet. If you need the schematic I can provide you the one with the USB-C port

Your device has 10k or 22k resistors to 5V. The role is fixed to be a DFP, which means it sources power and is a data host, and can't change role.

Yes i know that, that's why I put 10k/22k resistors. But why in practice, I have either power delivery from the USB-C or the data delivery? I can't have them simultaneously? I would like to have the PD while sending or recieving data from the USB-C. Because I setted the USB ad a DFP, I initiate the USB as an host so I should be able to receive data and if I want send data to the tablet, am I right?

Your resistors define the role and without further negotiations you are fixed to the role of the resistors. Initially, on DFP port, USB data host (e.g. computer) provides power to USB device (e.g. mouse). Without further communications, the devices will not change role. Communication for that in USB-C happens via USB PD protocol, and your device seems to be unable to negotiate via PD as it has no chipset for that.

So I should integrate a USB C PD controller to the PCB to have a setted USB C port as a DFP?

I have never used this kind of chip before so I am a little bit confused with what I jave read about this subject. With a device that work as a USB PD controller that can be either DFP/UFP mode, I can change the data role between the PCB and the android device while keeping the same PD status (the source is the PCB and the android device sink)? I can achieve that only with a USB C PD controller like the TPS26750?

@Yolnit I did not check what that chip is but basically some MCUs have PD communication PHY so you can send any commands over PD. Next problem is, will your tablet handle that as well. It sounds like you simply need a "docking station" between tablet and your ESP.

I'll look for that, I would have liked an embedded solution integreted to the PCB but I won't wasting my time for something that couldn't work well. I took the time to check other chips and there is the  PHY PD controller TUSB320IRWBR that can be used as DRP,DFP, UFP with DRD integrated. It seems better in my case that the one I shared you before. Do you have any idea about some experiments/tests that could lead me to the conclusion that the tablet won't handle it well? I don't think I can find any schematic online...

I have some news about the subject. After several discussions, it seems I need to have a PD controler more than a CC controler. I also need to program my device as a slave for the data transfert so I can keep the DFP configuration on while receiving or sending data from the PCB. I also checked some products from FTDI to see if I can chose a USB UART driver to configure the device as a slave and not like an host, but I can't find any component that can give me that config.

@Yolnit I think the big picture is missing. Basically, are you making a "docking station", which has power supply input, one internal USB port for UART, and one connection to laptop which gets charged and can see the USB UART?

The environment in which I'm going to use the card doesn't allow me to use a commercial docking station. To resituate the problem, I want to integrate a turnkey solution on my electronic board. There is one and only one USBC port, which must be in source/DFP mode for power delivery. I need to be able to read and write data from the tablet and the PCB, while the tablet is still charged.

After a bit of research, I saw that you had to use a PD controller and write a bit pattern to the CC pins of the USBC to tell the tablet “this is how you should work, I'm host in terms of power delivery, but I'm slave in data”, for example. I don't have enough hindsight to say whether this solution is optimal or not. An example of a PD controller that would do the trick would be a TPS25751 that I could program using EEPROM. I don't know if there's anything simpler than that, without going through the docking station.
